# Running Cassandra from IntelliJ and get error "connection refused"

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to experiment with Cassandra on my system with the below configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Kernel: 4.10.1
Cassandra source GitHub link: https://github.com/apache/cassandra
Setup process on IntelliJ link: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInIDEA
```

I open a terminal and run the below commands from the root directory of Cassandra source code without any failure:

```
bin/cassandra -f (it starts Cassandra successfully)
bin/nodetool status (Get information about the node e.g. datacenter, status etc.)
bin/cqlsh (opens the interface for running the queries)
```

However, when I follow the setup process for IntelliJ, I'm able to start the server from IntelliJ by hitting "*Run*" but "*nodetool status*" command always returns the below error:

```
Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused).
```

Interestingly, when i run "bin/cqlsh" command, it connects successfully, which means the node is running just fine.

Any idea what might be causing "*nodetool status*" to return "connection refused"?
I also tried turning the firewall off but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding some more VM arguments as below:

```
Add the following VM arguments if you want to use nodetool

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$JMX_HOST (I entered 127.0.0.1)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT (I entered 7199)
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Here is the link for reference: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse

These VM arguments are not provided in the wiki page for Cassandra setup with IntelliJ: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInIDEA (posted in my question as well).